# How can I set a different class to past dates on the jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a way to set previous *selected* dates of the jQuery UI Datepicker to a different class?

The scenario I am dealing with is that there is a calendar with upcoming events and previous events. The upcoming events right now get a class applied to them and are styled accordingly. I need to do the same for previous dates that had an event.

So for instance:

**May 10th** would be colored gold (*highlight* class) because it's an upcoming event.

**May 8th** would be colored a light gray (*passed-event* class) because it's a previous event.

Here is what I have so far (working from [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)):

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var result = [true, '', null],
                        afterOrToday = $.grep(events, function(event) {

                            var eventDate = new Date(event.Date),
                                todaysDate = new Date();

                            return date.valueOf() === eventDate.valueOf();
                        }),
                        beforeToday = $.grep(events, function(event) {

                            var eventDate = new Date(event.Date),
                                todaysDate = new Date();

                            return date.valueOf() < eventDate.valueOf();
                        });

                    if (afterOrToday.length)
                        result = [true, 'highlight', null];
                    else if (beforeToday.length)
                        result = [true, 'passed-event', null];

                    return result;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example http://jsbin.com/imiyez/1/edit:

You can compare dates without valueOf:

```
[true, ('past' if date < yesterday )]
```

Comment: I need to only apply a class to a certain date. All previous dates won't have this class. Only previous dates that had an event.

Comment: replace yesterday with the day of that event, what's the format of event date, is it a date object?

Comment: Another thing, can you see code in the link I shared? Link edited

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the most efficient method, and would love recommendations on changes to improve quality, but here is the solution I came up with.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var result = [true, '', null],
        today = $.grep(events, function(event) {

            var eventDate = new Date(event.Date);

            return date.valueOf() === eventDate.valueOf();
        }),
        beforeToday = $.grep(events, function(event, i) {

            var eventDate = new Date(event.Date),
                isPast = false;

            if (date.valueOf() === eventDate.valueOf())
                if (date.valueOf() < new Date().valueOf())
                    isPast = true;

            return isPast;
        });

    if (today.length)
        result = [true, 'highlight', null];

    if (beforeToday.length)
        result = [true, 'past-event', null];

    return result;
}
```

This will add a class to my past dates that had events as well as future dates in 2 separate classes. Thanks for the help everyone!